# Filtering HTML elements, using static HTML elements or dynamic using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a 'multiple filter' functionality to filter out certain HTML elements based on the the values selected by the user. You can see it here:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
const filters = document.querySelectorAll('.filter');
const filterOne = document.getElementById('filterOne');
const filterTwo = document.getElementById('filterTwo');
let filterArray = [];

function filterItems() {
  let stringFilter = filterOne.value;
  if (filterTwo.value) {

    stringFilter = filterOne.value.concat(filterTwo.value);
  }
  console.log(stringFilter)
  let filteredItems = [...items];
  filteredItems.filter(item => {
    if (item.textContent.includes(stringFilter)) {
      item.style.display = 'block';
      return item;
    } else {
      item.style.display = 'none';
    }
  })

}

[...filters].forEach(filter => {
  filter.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    filterItems(e.target.value);
  })
})
```

```css
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="filterContainer">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="filterOne">Value</label>
    <select class='filter' id="filterOne" name="filterOne">
      <option value=""> All </option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="filterContainer">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="filterTwo">Priority</label>
    <select class='filter' id="filterTwo" name="filterTwo">
      <option value=""> All </option>
      <option value="one">one</option>
      <option value="two">two</option>
      <option value="three">three</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-1">
    <h1>1</h1>
    <span class="priority">one</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-2">
    <h1>2</h1><span class="priority">two</span></div>
  <div class="item item-3">
    <h1>3</h1><span class="priority">one</span></div>
  <div class="item item-4">
    <h1>4</h1><span class="priority">two</span></div>
  <div class="item item-5">
    <h1>3 4 5 6 7</h1><span class="priority">one</span></div>
  <div class="item item-6">
    <h1>6</h1><span class="priority">three</span></div>
  <div class="item item-7">
    <h1>7</h1><span class="priority">one</span></div>
  <div class="item item-8">
    <h1>8</h1><span class="priority">two</span></div>
  <div class="item item-9">
    <h1>9</h1><span class="priority">three</span></div>
  <div class="item item-10">
    <h1>10</h1><span class="priority">one</span></div>
  <div class="item item-11">
    <h1>11</h1><span class="priority">one</span></div>
  <div class="item item-12">
    <h1>12</h1><span class="priority">two</span></div>
  <div class="item item-13">
    <h1>13</h1><span class="priority">two</span></div>
</div>
```

Now I would say that my example is rough but it does the job. You do have to manually change things if you want to add more filters in the future, but it works, and more importantly, the HTML is rendered on the server-side so I don't dynamically generate it which could cause any issues.

That got me thinking, "Wouldn't it be easier to create like an array of objects that I can use to dynamically generate the html for these items?". I think it would make the whole filtering process a lot easier but I was curious about other people's oppinions regarding this matter.

What are your thoughts? Thanks

Static generation of html and using a filtering function that takes in the values of the filter along with the textContent of the individual item.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Is there a specific problem?

Comment: Whether its easier or not is difficult to say and depends on many things. Generally speaking, javascript frameworks have their advantages, but having static html (or generate it from php for instance) is not bad, either. It depends on your project.

Comment: Sorry, my main question is about the pros and cons of using javascript to dynamically generate HTML in order to make the filtering process easier or is my approach "good"as is?

Comment: And array to store the relevant items, so that you don't have to edit static HTML, would certainly make sense. But regarding the filtering itself, it probably won't have too many benefits - whether you do `item.textContent.includes(stringFilter)`, or perform the same operation on an object property for items from an array, that makes little difference. (Only you would then still have to make the connection between the array entry, and the actual HTML element that needs to be shown or hidden, so that would be an _extra_ step.)

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, I also took that into consideration when creating this static solution.

Comment: You dont really gain much from inserting html elements from a javascript array. You somehow have to store the relevant data anyways, even in js, and with a good coding editor its not really a big deal. But again, its also not necessarily bad. It has down sides, but minor ones I guess. Anyways, this leads to a opinion based discussion and is probably the wrong place here.

Comment: @MihailescuFanushGabriel If youre interested in dynamic javascript/ html have a look at modern frameworks such as vue, next, angular, etc

Comment: @Alex understood, yeah, I'm working on React right now, it's more like a side project that my employer wants to do in vanilla js

Comment: One other question that I have is about my approach, is it good? How would you go about implementing multiple filters using select options?